# ¿Es correcto usar un if dentro de otro?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Me interesa saber si es correcto usar **un `if` dentro de otro**, para asegurarme que lo que construya después no me dé problemas o cualquier otro detalle y que no tenga que construir todo desde cero.

```js
var x = "texto";
var a = "texto";

var counter = document.querySelectorAll(".counter > span");

function contar() {

    if (x == a) {

        if (counter.length != 0) {
            alert("Hay etiquetas");
        } else {
            alert("No hay etiquetas");
        }
    }
}

contar();
```

```html
<div class="counter">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sería interesante que nos compartas el enunciado que tratas de resolver, por que de forma corta la respuesta es: `<<si>>`

Comment: Si bien es bastante común encontrar 'if' anidados y puede funcionar a la perfección, la realidad es que seria ideal dividir en funciones y que cada una devuelve el valor esperado. No solo por una buena practica de código, sino para poder encontrar errores en el futuro y para entendimiento a los demás desarrolladores. saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Está bien usar un `if` dentro de otro, pero es recomendable usar la menor cantidad de `if` posibles. También se puede usar un `switch`.

Podemos analizar los posibles valores:

- Si `x` es `a`

  - Si `counter.length` no es `0`

    1. `x` es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`
  - Si no (`counter.length` es `0`)

    2. `x` es `a` y `counter.length` es `0`
- Si no (`x` no es `a`)

  3. `x` no es `a` y `counter.length` puede ser cualquier cosa.

El tercer caso no se usa. Veamos qué ocurre si juntamos los dos `if` en uno solo.

- Si `x` es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`

  1. `x` es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`

En caso contrario probamos todas las combinaciones posibles y eliminamos la anterior. Como son dos condiciones, y cada uno puede ser o no ser equivalente, entonces hay 4 posibles.

1. `x` es `a` y `counter.length` es `0`
2. <strike>`x` es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`</strike>
3. `x` no es `a` y `counter.length` es `0`
4. `x` no es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`

Ya eliminamos la segunda. Nos queda así.

1. `x` es `a` y `counter.length` es `0`
2. `x` no es `a` y `counter.length` es `0`
3. `x` no es `a` y `counter.length` no es `0`

Los puntos 2 y 3 pueden unificarse a `x!=a`. Podemos dar vuelta las condiciones.

1. `counter.length` es `0` y `x` es `a`
2. `counter.length` es `0` y `x` no es `a`
3. `counter.length` no es `0` y `x` no es `a`

Los puntos 1 y 2 pueden unificarse a `counter.length==0`.

Entonces las dos siguientes expresiones son equivalentes:

- `x==a && counter.length==0 || x!=a`
- `x!=a && counter.length!=0 || counter.length==0`

Entonces los condicionales quedan así:

```
if(x==a && counter.length!=0){
    x==a && counter.length!=0
}else{
    x==a && counter.length==0 || x!=a
    x!=a && counter.length!=0 || counter.length==0
}
```

Volvemos al `if` dentro del otro para ver si coincide:

```
if( x==a && counter.length!=0 ){
    x==a && counter.length!=0
}else{
    x==a && counter.length==0
}
```

Aquí notamos al comparar que el `if` coincide, y el `else` también coincide el primero, pero no contempla que `x` no es `a`, porque lo está dejando afuera:

```
x!=a && counter.length==0
x!=a && counter.length!=0
```

En conclusión, podemos ver en este caso que **no solo es correcto usar uno dentro de otro, si no que además es necesario usarlos**.

Otro ejemplo, esta vez no usamos el `else`:

```
if(x==a) {
    if(counter.length!=0){
        // x es a y counter.length no es 0
    }
}
```

En este caso, como no hay `else`, lo que se hace dentro del `if` es el único caso posible.

```
if(x==a && counter.length!=0){
    // x es a y counter.length no es 0
}
```

Entonces en este caso, **pueden juntarse los `if` sin problemas**.

Por otra parte, para saber cuántas etiquetas hay dentro de una etiqueta hay que usar `.children.length`, esto busca las etiquetas y las cuenta.

Código:

```js
var etiqueta = document.querySelector("div")
var etiquetas = etiqueta.children
var cantidad_etiquetas = etiquetas.length
if(cantidad_etiquetas){
  console.log("Cantidad de etiquetas:", etiqueta.children.length)
  for(var i=0;i<cantidad_etiquetas;++i){
    console.log(etiquetas[i])
  }
}else{
  console.log("No hay etiquetas")
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Hola</p>
    <a>Mundo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esos son "if" anidados, dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, puedes poner todos los que quieras:

```
if(a>5){
  if(b<10){
   if(c==0){
   }
  }
}
```

su sintaxis sería algo asi, pero no es lo mismo que poner:

```
 if(a>5){
      if(b<10){
      }
      if(c==0){
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

para responder **rápidamente** tu pregunta, te digo que **si** (se conoce como `if` anidado o nested, en inglés).
Pero también te podría indicar(para el caso del `if` de tu pregunta) que utilices una condición adicional en tu `if`.

```
function contar() {
    if (x === a && counter.length != 0) {
        alert("Hay etiquetas");
    } else {
        alert("No hay etiquetas");
    }
}
```

Los operadores lógicos`||` y `&&` permiten agregar más condiciones a tu `if`. 
Puedes visitar [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) para más información referente a lo indicado arriba

Answer (score 2):

Sí es correcto, pero los [*operadores ternarios*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) para casos como estos, ayudan mucho a simplificar el código.

```js
var x = "texto";
var a = "texto";
var counter = document.querySelectorAll(".counter > span");

function contar() {
  if (x == a) {
    alert((counter.length != 0) ? "Hay etiquetas" : "No hay etiquetas");
  }
}

contar();
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

El `if`  fue cambiado por esto:

```
    alert((counter.length != 0) ? "Hay etiquetas" : "No hay etiquetas");
```

La sintaxis es muy simple:

```
(condición) ? expresión1 : expresión2
```

- `condición`: es la parte que se va a evaluar
- `expresión1`: si `condición`  es verdadero
- `expresión2`: si `condición` es falso

Si interesará evaluar también a `x` en el mismo paquete, los `if` podrían sustituirse totalmente:

```js
var x = "texto";
var a = "textos";
var counter = document.querySelectorAll(".counter > span");

function contar() {
    alert((counter.length != 0 && x === a) ? "Hay etiquetas" : "No hay etiquetas");
}

contar();
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Hay también operadores ternarios para evaluaciones complejas y anidadas.